# Laravel 4.2 Input form field, if pass expression(1+1=2) gives error Method not allowed

Tags: forms, laravel-4, laravel-routing

Whenever I type normal text like (abc xyz etc ) it submits the form properly, while If I type some expression in input field, it gives method not allowed error. I didn't added any server side validation.

```
{{ Form::open(array('url' => route("testme"), 'id' => 'test-form', 'method' => 'post', 'class' => 'test-form input-blocks')) }}
    <div class="grid_3 alpha">
        <div class="field">
            <label for="name"><strong>Your Name</strong> <span class="text-red">*</span></label>
            {{ Form::text('name','',array('id' => 'name'))}}
        </div>
    </div>

  <div class="grid_9 alpha omega">
      <button class="button" type="submit" name="submit" id="submit">Send Message</button>
      <div id="response"></div>
  </div>

{{Form::close()}}
```

when typing expression in input eg: (`1+1=2 or 1=1=1`), even I am not able to land on my `Route::post();`

Here are my routes

```
Route::post('testme', ['as'=>'testme-post','uses'=> function(){
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r(Input::all());
    die();
}]);
```

Please guide, what can be issue, I tried all ways but no luck.
On my local machine all is working fine but on live site, it gives error.

Error screenshot is attached.[image]

Comment: 'url' => route("testme") can be route=>'testme'

Comment: @DsRaj this not solution, Please read my thread again

Comment: can you please share your screenshot with current URL?